# Laravel View Composer variables not accessible in views that extend layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using a Laravel view composer to share a couple of variables with all views.

`app/composers.php`:

```
View::composer('layouts.base', 'MyApp\Composers\BaseComposer');
```

My understanding here is that anything that uses `layouts.base` will get the view composer data.

`BaseComposer@compose`, simplified:

```
 public function compose($view) {
      // Some logic left out here that pulls in some data

      $data = array(
        'name' => 'John',
        'status' => 'active'
      );

      $data = (object) $data;

      return $view->with('global', $data);
    }
```

Given this `layouts.base`:

```
  {{ $global->name }}

  @include('layouts.partials.header')

  @yield('content')
```

`$global->name` is found and so is this in the included `layouts.partials.header`:

```
  {{ $global->status }}
```

But, a view that extends `layouts.base` throws an `Undefined variable: global` error:

`home.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.base')
@section('content')
  {{ $global->name }}
@stop
```

Everything works fine if I modify `composers.php` to reference `home`:

```
View::composer(['layouts.base', 'home'], 'MyApp\Composers\BaseComposer');
```

I'd like to understand why if `home` extends `layouts.base` it can't see the view composer variables without this extra step.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is the order of how things happen. View composers get called *before the matching view* gets rendered. That means in your case:

1. view `home` gets rendered
2. view composer for `layouts.base` gets called
3. view `layouts.base` gets rendered

This results in the variable `global` not being available in the `home` view.

Here are some solutions that may help

#### Change the composer pattern

Change your composer match pattern to include all the views that need the variable. Make use of the wildcard `*` if possible.
You can even match each and every view:

```
View::composer('*', 'MyApp\Composers\BaseComposer');
```

#### Don't use composers at all

If you need your data in (nearly) every view anyways you can use `View::share` during start of the application.

Put this in `app/filters.php`, `app/start/global.php` or a similar file

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'status' => 'active'
);

$data = (object) $data;

View::share('global', $data);
```

#### Rethink

Why do different views need the same global data? Could you maybe move the part of the view that needs the data into a partial view which you can then include?

Comment: Thanks lukasgeiter. I ended up similar to your suggestion by placing the logic that used the composer vars in a partial.

Comment: Well this is disappointing. &commat;extends is &commat;extends is &commat;extends is &commat;extends. It implies that the extending view IS_A extended view, and so should HAVE everything the extended view HAS. The framework should go out of its way to ensure this, even introducing a separate "collect view composers from &commat;extends hierarchy" pass if necessary.

Comment: SSSHHHHHHH... Failed to figure out how to quote those gosh-darned at-signs within 5 minutes available to edit a comment...

Comment: I highly dis-encourage to use wildcard. I am currently on a project where a page took 45 seconds to load. Turned out, the developer used wildcards and for every blade that was included (footer, header, widgets) all queries were duplicated resulting in this crazy time..

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'status' => 'active'
);

$data = (object) $data;

View::share('global', $data);
```